# How to make an input of unorganized numbers into an array/matrix and sum specific numbers

Tags: python, arrays, input

I have this problem where i get an console input that is not an array/matrix, **it's just a bunch of numbers per line separated by a space**. How do i turn them in a actual array?

OBS about the input **(the input it's not an txt or csv, it's directly the terminal inputing me numbers separated by space)**

My given input is like this:

```
4 3 2 1 3 4 2 2 3 3 2 1 2 3
4 4 1 3 2 1 4 2 4 1 1 1 4 3
4 4 4 1 2 2 3 4 2 1 1 2 1 1
1 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 3 2 4 1
1 3 3 2 2 2 4 4 3 2 1 4 4 3
2 1 4 3 2 2 2 4 3 1 2 3 1 1
4 1 3 4 2 4 3 3 2 4 2 2 1 1
1 1 4 3 4 1 3 3 2 2 1 1 3 1
4 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 3 2 2 1 2 3
```

And for now i'm doing this:

```
string_data = input()
arr = [[int(num) for num in sublist.split()] for sublist in string_data.split('\n') if len(sublist)>0]
print(arr)
```

This solution kinda works.. **but only for the first line**, so the input from the code above will be:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

I need to find a way to merge this into an full array without creating the code that i wrote for each line. **My main problem is to turn my input into an array so that I can add every time the number 2 appears.... so if it appears 5 times, the program needs to read it and return me the number 10**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.fromstring`

```
import numpy as np

string_data = str(input())

np.fromstring(string_data, dtype=int, sep="\n")
```

Comment: but i have more than an input, if i do this with the input he just get's the first line like "4 3 2 1 3 4 2 2 3 3 2 1 2 3"

Comment: @MuriloMagalhães does the edited version help it now?

Comment: Yes Thanks! i mean, it still only get the first line of input, but i can simply repeat for each line. ty

Comment: It converts the whole input to an array in my case. What do you mean by the first line of the input?